# What are some practical examples of the use of a Luhmann box?

Tags: note-taking

I've been looking at implementing a [Zettelcasten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zettelkasten). There are a ton of resources on the internet, including questions [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104579/system-for-organising-printed-papers-in-folders/104582#104582) as well as YouTube videos on how to [set up your slip box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMJGKZ7n9hE&t=104s) and someone working through [their own box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw640AepjFM).

I understand that the first question one should ask oneself when adding a new note is: "When do I want this information to appear?". This seems straight forward.

So, when adding a note, one puts it amongst notes to which it is most closely related. Let's make an example.

1. Economy
2. Human psychology
3. Cryptocurrency

Under each one of these we might have sub-categories and the final notes. Is the purpose to find insight *across* these categories and hypothetically write an essay with: 1.A.2, 2.B.1.A, 2.B.1.B and 3.A.2? Or, should I be adding notes in such a way that each category can become an essay on its own?

Comment: I'd never heard of this system before but now I want to try it out, thanks!

Comment: The idea of a Zettelkasten is to avoid imposing a fixed hierarchy, but rather showing the connections between thoughts. The Luhmann identifier style is an artifact of using a physical Zettelkasten where cards necessarily need a a sensible order. Digital systems don't have such constraints.